# Règle d'accord pour les aliments

Tags: grammaire, pluriel, alimentation

Quelle est la règle qui détermine si les ingrédients d'un plat doivent se mettre au singulier ou au pluriel?

Par exemple :

- une tarte aux pommes
- une tarte aux abricots
- une tarte au citron
- une tarte à la rhubarbe

Comment: Bizarrement je dirais le fait que le fruit en question soit encore reconnaissable ou pas.

Comment: À mon avis cette question me semble partir sur un a priori faux. Car il est tout aussi correct et habituel de dire *une tarte à la pomme /à l'abricot/au citron* qu'*une tarte aux pommes/aux abricots/aux citrons*. J'étais sur le point d'écrire qu'il n'y a que pour rhubarbe que le singulier s'impose et par prudence j'ai googlé "tarte aux rhubarbes" et 
j'ai eu des retours dont [un] (http://www.oralhistoryforum.ca/index.php/ohf/article/download/167/216) qui semble sérieux.

Comment: Par contre en tant que cuisinière (on n'est plus dans le français !)  si j'utilise plusieurs variétés de pommes (de citrons, de bananes, etc...) pour faire une seule et même tarte je dirai que je fais une *tarte aux pommes* (*aux citrons, aux bananes*) et je m'interdirais le singulier dans ce cas.

Comment: @Knu : Quand je fais une tarte en mélangeant citrons jaunes et citrons verts, je dis que je fais une "tarte aux **citrons**" et les citrons sont en jus et donc pas "reconnaissables" par la forme.

Comment: @Laure: Merci pour ton commentaire. Tu devrais le mettre en réponse pour que je puisse l'accepter.

Comment: @laure oui mais tu changes le sens car *en gros* "tarte au citron" veut dire au goût citron, alors que "tarte aux citrons" plutôt tarte garni de citrons. Même si tu utilises différentes variétés de citron je resterais sur "tarte au citron".

Comment: Et dans certains cas, on ne met rien du tout, par exemple "tarte coco", "tarte chocolat-noisettes".

Comment: @M42 : Je ne répondais pas vraiment à ta question, je pointais juste des questions de français et de cuisine ! Le but de ce forum n'est quand même pas d'accumuler des points à tout prix mais de progresser dans la connaissance du français.  Donc je préfère en rester là ;-)

Est-on obligé d'accepter une réponse d'ailleurs ?

Comment: @rds : ou "chocolat-noisette" !

Comment: @Laure: Ton pont de vue se défend parfaitement, je disais ça juste pour les lecteurs suivants qui se poseraient la même question. On a plutôt tendance à regarder les réponses à une question que les commentaires.

Comment: Chez moi, quand on fait de la soupe à l'oignon, on ne met qu'un oignon.

Comment: @Joubarc: tout dépend de la quantité d'eau, vin et autres ingrédients qui accompagnent l'oignon, c'est peut-être quand même mangeable au final.

Comment: En fait elle était même excellente, mais il n'y avait qu'un bol.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ça ne me paraît pas une règle officielle, mais je pense que cela vient du fait que le contenu soit utilisé généralement comme un dénombrable ou pas:

- une tarte aux pommes car on y mets **des** pommes
- une tarte aux abricots car on y mets **des** abricots
- une tarte au citron car on y mets **du** citron
- une tarte à la rhubarbe car on y mets **de la** rhubarbe

On peut aussi dire "une tarte faite avec **des** citrons", mais c'est plus commun de dire "avec **du** citron" car la tarte est généralement faite avec le jus de citron.

Comment: Ca semblait une explication possible, mais finalement il y a trop de contre-exemples : "tarte à la tomate", "tarte à l'oignon", "tarte au citron" (dénombrable, cela aurait du être "tarte aux citrons" si l'on suivait cette règle)

Comment: @rds sur ta "tarte à la tomate" tu mets de la sauce tomate: si tu mets des tomates entières ça devient une tarte aux tomates.

Comment: @rds: Je ne dis pas que la règle est basée sur le caractère dénombrable du fruit, mais sur l'utilisation habituelle du déterminant (on dit plus souvent *du* citron que *des* citrons).

Comment: @Otiel : Dans une *tarte au citron*, moi je mets **des citrons** plutôt que **du citron**. De même que dans une *tarte aux pommes* (ou *à la pomme*) on met le plus souvent **des pommes**.

Comment: @laure un exemple répandu : la mention chocolat *à l'orange* est souvent utilisé sur les emballages pour signifier *à l'arôme d'orange* (ne contenant pas forcément du vrai fruit et donc trompe certains, comme toi apparemment).

Comment: @rds Et pourtant, c'est la bonne explication... Certains noms sont considérés comme des goûts, des matières, et certains, comme des ingrédients qui entrent en grand nombre dans un plat. C'est l'explication qu'on trouve dans maints livres de grammaire, et la seule que j'ai jamais entendue de plausible. Les contre-exemples ne sont pas une infirmation, surtout concernant ce genre de règles.

Comment: "Dans une tarte au citron, moi je mets des citrons plutôt que du citron" Ce n'est pas à propos d'une utilisation personnelle, c'est à propos de la façon dont le mot s'est "inséré" en français. Il y a une logique commune à une langue (qui peut évoluer). De plus, faire une tarte au citron, et une tarte aux citrons sont deux sens et deux tartes totalement différents.

Answer (score 4):

J'irais dans le sens [de Knu](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/1635/regle-daccord-pour-les-aliments?rq=1#comment3034_1635) : on va plus facilement dire « une tarte aux poires » si on est capable de distinguer les poires dessus, et un gâteau *à la poire* s'il est « au goût de poire », sans morceaux.

Parfois, les différentes formes sont correctes, selon qu'on désigne *les* différents « objets d'ingrédient » qu'on à mis dedans, ou *le* goût qu'a le résultat (typiquement, *des* pommes, ou *à la* pomme).

Par contre, **si on n'utilise un seul ingrédient, j'employerais le singulier**. J'inclus là-dedans le cas où l'ingrédient est indénombrable — *un* melon, *de la* noix de coco rapée, etc.

Je dirais donc un gâteau « à la carotte » s'il est fait avec une quantité indénombrable *de* carotte rapée, mais un ragoût « aux carottes » s'il est évident qu'il y en a *plusieurs*. Une tarte « au citron » si faite avec *du* jus, mais « aux citrons confits » s'il y en a *plusieurs* morceaux, etc.

<sub>J'ai faim maintenant.</sub>

Comment: Oui. Une tarte à la poire, et une tarte avec un goût de poire. Une tarte aux poires, c'est une tarte où on voit les poires de façon bien apparente. (sens général).