# Do any rules of thumb exist for prepositions used in food?

Tags: prépositions, alimentation

I’m often struggling to find the correct preposition to use when describing food, for example:

- soupe **de** poisson
- confiture **aux** fraises
- frites **avec** mayonnaise

Are other combinations possible, like “*soupe au poisson*” or “*confiture de fraises*”? If so, do they still mean exactly the same? I’d like to learn some guidelines of when to use which preposition.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Règle d'accord pour les aliments](http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/1635/regle-daccord-pour-les-aliments)

Comment: @CédricJulien pas vraiment, la présente question est plus générique (utilisation de `de` / `à` / `avec`) alors que la question que tu mentionnes porte plus sur le doute singulier/pluriel.

Comment: @AlexisPigeon : la question d'accord, mais la réponse me semblait être assez appropriée (dénombrables/non dénombrables). Mais si les questions ne sont pas des doublons, elles sont néanmoins très liées :)

Comment: I was learning about Flavors recently and the rule that I use is as follows: Determine the gender of the ingredient, for example possion is masculine, then since (a+le=au), we can write la soupe au poisson. Similarly, since fraises is plural (a+les=aux), we can write la confiture aux fraises and so on

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Et *soupe aux choux*, *confiture d'orange* (en passant, *confiture de fraises* me semble plus courant que *confiture aux fraises*, et Google semble confirmer en trouvant environ dix fois plus de résultats).

Pour moi,

- *avec* introduit un accompagnement et non un ingrédient
- *de* introduit plutôt un ingrédient principal, si pas unique, qui a pu ne pas être utilisé totalement
- *à* introduit plutôt un ingrédient secondaire ou du moins utilisé avec d'autres qui sont d'importance comparable, et qui a été consommé complètement.

Mais c'est le genre de chose où en voulant établir des règles, on s'éloigne de l'usage.

Voir les entrées pour [à](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/%C3%A0) et [de](http://cntrl.fr/definition/de) dans le TLFi.

Answer (score 1):

Pour ce qui est d'*avec*, il s'agit d'un complément alimentaire de l'ingrédient principal, souvent pour le valoriser ou en changer le goût afin de varier les menus lorsque le constituant de base revient régulièrement dans l'assiette.

On peut dire une *configure **de** fraise* lorsque les fraises sont les seuls fruits utilisés, et on dira plutôt alors une *configure **aux** fraises* lorsqu'elles représentent la plus grande partie des fruits utilisés, mais que le goût est rehaussé par un ou des ingrédients (qui peuvent être des fruits) secondaires.

On n'emploie pas *une soupe aux poissons*, car, même s'il y a parfois des crustacés dedans, c'est une recette en soi.