# When to use “de”, “à” or “au / à la / aux” in noun complements?

Tags: prépositions, articles

I would like to understand whether there is a pattern on usage of “de”, “à“ or “à la” as complements to noun:

> un cours de natation
>
> une cuillère à café
>
> une glace à la fraise
>
> un bateau à moteur

Comment: Some indications on how to differenciate cases when to use *à* or *au / à la / aux* : http://french.stackexchange.com/q/6346/1129

Comment: This may be too broad for a single question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Le sujet fait une vingtaine de pages chez Grevisse... Je résume fortement (et donc c'est principalement des tendances avec des exceptions)

En général,

- *de* est la préposition normale,
- il y a un certain nombre de cas où *à* marque l'appartenance dans l'usage régulier, et ils sont encore plus répandus dans le parler populaire.

Pour les noms dérivés de verbes,

- les compléments correspondant à des agents de verbes ou des COD sont introduits par *de* (Pierre aime, l'amour de Pierre; aimer les enfants, l'amour des enfants); quand les deux sont présents, pour les sentiments c'est l'agent qui est introduit par *de*, le COD est introduit par une autre préposition (Pierre aime les enfants, l'amour de Pierre pour les enfants); dans les autres cas, c'est le COD qui est introduit par *de* et l'agent par *par* (la France conquit l'Algérie, la conquête de l'Algérie par la France)
- lorsque le COD a un sens partitif, on utilise *à* (moudre du café, un moulin à café)
- les COI gardent leur préposition (participer à la conférence, la participation à la conférence; entrer dans la maison, l'entrée dans la maison).

Comment: Merci, Est-ce que vous pouvez me expliquer qu'est-ce que ce veut dire «sens partitif», s'il vous plait?

Comment: Sens partitif veut dire qu'il ne concerne qu'une partie de l'objet.  En général la construction avec un verbe utilise un article partitif (**du** ici). En passant, http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/5798/do-any-rules-of-thumb-exist-for-prepositions-used-in-food.

Answer (score 0):

**à means at,to,in etc and le,la,les are definite articles**

**à le** should be replaced with    (le is used for masculine)  -—> **au**

**à la** should be same as  (la is used for feminine)-—>**à la**

**à l’** should be same as (l’ used before words starting with vowel or h)  -—>**à l’**

**à les** should be replaced with (les is used before plural no matter feminine or masculine)-—> **aux**